# NumberFormatException when converting varchar(500) latin1_swedish_ci mysql datatype to integer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have one issue.

Currently, i'm trying to convert the string value to integer. In this case, the string value is the one from the database whose data type is varchar(500) latin1_swedish_ci.

After extracting the value from the database, i want to convert to integer as I have some further processing as an integer value.

Below is my code.

```
String order_number="";
    DbEngine db = new DbEngine();
    String select_max_order_id = " SELECT MAX( orderid ) AS orderid FROM `orders` ";
    try{
        Connection con = db.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        PreparedStatement prp_select = con.prepareStatement(select_max_order_id);

        ResultSet rs = prp_select.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            order_number=rs.getString("orderid");
            int order_no = Integer.parseInt("order_number");
            order_no+=1;
            order_number = Integer.toString(order_no);
        }
        con.commit();
        con.close();
    }
    catch( SQLException ex ) {
        System.out.println("Error"+ex.getSQLState());
    } 
    catch( ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
        System.out.println("Error"+ex.getException());
    } 
    catch( NumberFormatException  ex ) {
        System.out.println("Parsing Error"+ex.getStackTrace());
    }
```

The problem is when order_number is parsed to string value, throws NumberFormatException.
This is the stack trace from server. [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@257f04

However, when i pass the exact string value like int order_no = Integer.parseInt("10");

Can anyone suggest me how to solve it please?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to add `ex.printStackTrace();` into your catch blocks and then edit your post to show what the stacktrace is?

Comment: If your field should always contain a number, why are you using a varchar field at all?

Comment: Also, please be aware that this approach could lead to duplicate order numbers, if two new orders are created at exactly the same time.  You might want to consider using a sequence for your order number.

Answer (score 3):

You are just close to it.

you are trying to parse a string `"order_number"` and not your actual order number string `order_number`

```
order_number=rs.getString("orderid");
int order_no = Integer.parseInt(order_number);  // remove those quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Integer.parseInt(order_number);
```

It should be variable here.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the quotes.

Try, `Integer.parseInt(order_number);`, instead of `Integer.parseInt("order_number");`

Before you were parsing the string *order_number* rather than parsing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int order_no = Integer.parseInt("order_number");
```

When you say above statement you mean the string "order_number" is an integer and get me that(**which is not.**). You are storing your data in a string **named order_number**. So to retrieve your integer you must do -

```
int order_no = Integer.parseInt(order_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude problem is that u are trying to convert a string value to int which is not possible. The thing starts from here

Your code is here 
 order_number=rs.getString("orderid");
  int order_no = Integer.parseInt("order_number"); 
The order_number variable is String and you are converting it into int.
What u can do is make String select_max_order_id as int instead of int  and there on wards you  dont need any conversion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, actually orderid field is the varchar since the table is created. And, saving the orderid values is going in this way. It is generated by the program like just now what i'm doing. let's say, the maximum order id is 10, it will increment by 1, so becomes 11 and 11 will be saved into database. So, any idea on without doing any conversion plz?